# Increment value in DB when script is called

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get all update an `int` value in my database whenever the script is called. Just to put this issue into perspective, I have a table called `monthly_flagged`, which gets all the flagged posts on my site, and sorts them into the month they were flagged. The script is called `flagged_posts`. When the script is called, the idea is that the column `total_flagged` in table `monthly_flagged` will go up by one (+1).

However, with my current approach, the number doesn't change. The value currently is `0`, and I have flagged `3` posts, meaning `total_flagged` should equal 3, but it remains at 0 (no change).

Here is my approach:

```
$currentMonth = date('F'); // get month realtime
$currentYear = date ('Y'); // get year realtime

$check_month = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM monthly_flagged");
$get_month = mysqli_fetch_array ($check_month);
    $month = $get_month['month'];
    $year = $get_month['year'];
    $total_flagged = $get_month['total_flagged'];

// check if row exists in db for current month/year, else make it.
$checking_row = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM monthly_flagged WHERE month = '$currentMonth' AND year = '$currentYear' LIMIT 1");
$check_return = mysqli_num_rows ($checking_row);

if ($check_return == 0){
    $make_row = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO monthly_flagged VALUES ('', '$currentMonth', '$currentYear', '')");
}
if ($check_return == 1){
    $plusOne = $total_flagged +1;
    $update_total_flagged = mysqli_query ($connect, "UPDATE monthly_flagged WHERE month = '$currentMonth' AND year = '$currentYear' 
                                                    SET total_flagged = '$plusOne'");
}
```

Comment: just a tip: `SET total_flagged = total_flagged+1`

Comment: Try changing `if ($check_return == 1)` to `if ($check_return > 0)` and see if it triggers then.

Comment: @Dagon - I initially tried that approach, `SET total_flagged = '$total_flagged' +1`, but, having never used such an approach, and when it never worked, I resulted to my current approach

Comment: @The42ndDoctor - Just tried, still the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update statement you have the `WHERE` placed in front of the `SET` it should be:

```
UPDATE monthly_flagged 
SET total_flagged = '$plusOne'
WHERE month = '$currentMonth' AND year = '$currentYear'
```

Or without the plus one variable:

```
UPDATE monthly_flagged 
SET total_flagged = (total_flagged+1)
WHERE month = '$currentMonth' AND year = '$currentYear'
```

These kind of mistakes can be easily spotted if you implement something to catch MySQL errors (they're not magically displayed): [More info on error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

P.S. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections meaning other people can pretty much execute any SQL code on your database including deleting all. you should read up on prepared statements and how to use them! [More info on prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)